# XAML Deserialization problem

Tags: exception, xaml, serialization

I have a block of XAML of which i'm trying to deserialize.  For arguments sake lets say it looks like below.

```
<NS:SomeObject>
  <NS:SomeObject.SomeProperty>
    <NS:SomeDifferentObject SomeOtherProp="a value"/>
  </NS:SomeObject.SomeProperty>
</NS:SomeObject>
```

Of which i deserialise using the following code.

```
XamlReader.Load(File.OpenRead(@"c:\SomeFile.xaml"))
```

I have 2 solutions, one i use Unit Testing, and another i have for my web application.  When i'm using the unit testing solution, it deserializes fine and works as expected.  However, when i try to deserialize using my other project i keep getting an exception like the following.

> 'NameSpace.SomeObject' value cannot be assigned to property 'SomeProperty' of object 'NameSpace.SomeObject'.  Object of Type 'NameSpace.SomeObject' cannot be converted to type 'NameSpace.SomeObject'.

It's as if it is getting confused or instantiating 2 different types of objects?  Note, i do not have similarly named classes or any sort of namespace conflict.  The same codes executes fine in one solution and not the other.  The same project files are referenced in both.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Resetting IIS seemed to have fixed the problem.  XAML must have been using a shadow copy of the DLL's *sigh*